# How do I validate a large json file using Node JS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file of 398 MB. I want to check if all the JSON elements are well formatted  or not. Since the file size is too large, I am unable to check the elements manually. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: if works its valid, if not it can be readen in JS. for validate, this will made in Java

Comment: There is a nice module [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json)

Answer (score 1):

In java,

If you have a schema file for JSON, you can use fge/json-schema-validator. Just make sure you derive a ProcessingReport object and return it for report purpose:

One example would be this:
https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples/Example1.java

and more on explanation here:

https://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you MongoDb import module. If you can import your file to MongoDB it's valid.

```
mongoimport --db test --collection test_data --drop --file ~/myjsonfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs, you can do something like :

```
try {
     var parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringJson);
}
catch (ex) {

}
```

But your JSON must be loaded. 398MB needed at least this size in memory I suppose. Why is it so big ? Could you split it in smaller JSON file ?

Mickael